# Operator norm and spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $L$ be a bounded linear operator on a *Hilbert space*. Without assuming finite dimensions, can we express the operator norm of $L$ in terms of the spectrum of the positive operator $L^{\dagger}L$?

More precisely, does the following hold.

$\sup \big\{ \| L\phi \| \,\big|\, \phi \in \mathcal{H} \land \|\phi\| = 1  \big\} = \sqrt{ \max \sigma(L^{\dagger} L)}$

Comment: For $L^*L$ we have that $\|L^*L\| = r(L^*L)$ - spectral radious of $L^*L$, i.e. $r(L^*L) = \sup_{\lambda \in \sigma(L^*L)}\lambda$. Since $B(H)$ is a C*-algebra $\|L^*L\| = \|L\|^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will convert Frank's comment into the answer.

As it was showed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306576/19538) (theorem 3.4) for every normal element $a$ of a unital $C^*$-algebra $A$ holds
$$
\Vert a\Vert=r(a)
$$
For your particular case $A=\mathcal{B(H)}$ and $a=L^*L$. Using $C^*$-identity and the fact that $L^*L$ is normal we get
$$
\Vert L\Vert^2=\Vert L^*L\Vert=r(L^*L)=\max\sigma(L^*L)
$$