# Gelfand transform and spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $\mathcal A$ commutative, unital Banach algebra and denote by $\mathcal M(\mathcal A)$ the space of multiplicative functionals on $\mathcal A$. The Gelfand transform is defined by

$$\Gamma: \mathcal A \rightarrow \mathcal M(\mathcal A), \quad A \mapsto \Gamma(A),$$

where $\Gamma(A)(m)=m(A),\forall m\in \mathcal M(\mathcal A)$.

Why is the following implication true?

$$\Gamma(A) = 0 \Rightarrow \sigma(A) = \{0\}$$

($\sigma (A)$ is the spectrum of $A\in \mathcal A$)

Comment: The set $\Omega(A)=\mathcal{M}(A)\setminus\left\{0\right\}$ is usually used instead of $\mathcal{M}(A)$, and the Gelfand transform takes values in $C(\Omega(A))$ (or $C(\mathcal{M}(A)))$! See *G. J. Murphy, C$*$-Algebras and Operator Theory*, Theorem 1.3.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact $A\in\mathcal{A}$ is invertible iff $m(A)\neq 0$ for all $m\in\Omega(\mathcal{A}):=\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A})\setminus\{0\}$. As the consequence
we have the chain equivalences
$$
\begin{align}
\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\sigma(A)
&\Longleftrightarrow A-\lambda 1\in\mathrm{Inv}(\mathcal{A})\\ 
&\Longleftrightarrow \forall m\in \Omega(\mathcal{A})\quad m(A-\lambda 1)\neq 0\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \forall m\in \Omega(\mathcal{A})\quad\lambda\neq m(A)\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \lambda\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{m(A): m\in \Omega(\mathcal{A})\}
\end{align}
$$
This means that 
$$
\sigma(A)=\{m(A):m\in \Omega(A)\}=\{\Gamma(A)(m):m\in \Omega(A)\}
$$
For $A=0$ we obviously get $\sigma(A)=\{0\}$. For more details see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306576/19538).

Comment: Thanks! Why is $m(A-\lambda I)\neq 0 \Leftrightarrow m(a)\neq \lambda$? Is every multiplicative functional linear?

Comment: In Gelfand's theory they are assumed to be linear