# Maximal ideals of commutative unital C* algebra using Gelfand-Naimark theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, ideals, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a unital, commutative C*-algebra. The radical of $\mathcal{A}$ is defined as

$$\operatorname{Rad}(\mathcal{A}) = \bigcap \{\mathcal{I}\subset \mathcal{A}: \mathcal{I} \text{ is a maximal ideal}\}$$

How can one characterize $\operatorname{Rad}(\mathcal{A})$ using the Gelfand-Naimark theorem only, i.e. without referring to more evolved methods such as representation theory?

**EDIT**: (Gelfand-Naimark theorem)

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a unital commutative C*-algebra. Then the Gelfand transform $\Gamma: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow C(M(\mathcal{A})), \Gamma(A)(m):=m(A)$ is a *-isomorphism.

Comment: Think of kernel of Gelfand transform. If you still have no idea see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/306576/19538) (theorem 4.2)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: For any space $X$ and any $x\in X$, the set of functions vanishing at $x$ is a maximal ideal in $C(X)$.