# Spectrum of linear operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, spectral-theory

I can't solve the following:

i) Let $T:l^2 \rightarrow l^2$ , $Tx=\{ (Tx)_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ given by $$(Tx)_n = \dfrac{1}{2}x_{n-1} + \dfrac{1}{2}x_n.$$ 
Find $\sigma(T)$.

ii) Let $S : l^2 \rightarrow l^2$ defined by $l(x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots ) = (x_2, x_3, \dots )$
Find $\sigma(S)$.

iii) Let $X$ be a normed vector space and $T\colon X \rightarrow X$ linear operator such that $T^{-1}$ exists. Show that $$ \sigma(T^{-1}) = \{ \lambda^{-1} : \lambda \in \sigma (T) \}.$$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the statement $(Tx)_n = (\frac{1}{2}x_{n - 1} + \frac{1}{2}x_n)$, what do you mean by "$x_{n - 1}$" when $n = 1$?

Comment: Assume that $x_0=0$

Answer (score 2):

For paragraph ii) see [these notes](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m511/spectralExamples.pdf). In fact $\sigma(S)=\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}:|\lambda|\leq 1\}=\operatorname{Ball}_{\mathbb{C}}(0,1)$.

For paragraph iii) see theorem $1.3$ in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302158/gelfand-topology-and-c-algebras/306576#306576)

For paragraph i) note that $T=0.5(1_{\ell_2}+S)$, then
$$
\lambda\in\sigma(S)\Longleftrightarrow 0.5(1+\lambda)\in\sigma(T)
$$
hence $\sigma(T)=\operatorname{Ball}_{\mathbb{C}}(1,0.5)$